# FFmpeg and bash, Transcode multiple files to another drive with save path

Tags: bash, path, ffmpeg, save, transcoding

I have folder that contain files in many different path, for example: folder1/subfolder1/file.mov
folder1/subfolder2/file.mov

i need to convert and copy all files to another format, and save all paths after folder 1, for example:
folder2/subfolder1/file.mp4
folder2/subfolder2/file.mp4

I have this script, but it save transcoded files in original location.

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=/Volumes/drive/
find "$MOVIES" -name '*.MP4' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0 -c copy "${0%%.MP4}.mov"' {} \; exit;
```

Please help
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part `"${0%%.MP4}.mov"` with `"folder2/$(dirname ${0#*/})/$(basename $0 .MP4).mov"`. This won't tolerate MP4s with spaces in their paths.

Does ffmpeg create the directory? If not, insert just before the ffmpeg:

```
mkdir -p "folder2/$(dirname ${0#*/})";
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for long answer, now i have this. `code#!/bin/bash
MOVIES=~/Desktop/folder1/
find "$MOVIES" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "/Volumes/Victory/folder2/$(dirname ${0#*/})"; ffmpeg -i "$0" -c copy  "/Volumes/Victory/folder2/$(dirname ${0#*/})/$(basename $0 .MP4).mov"' {} \;
exit;` And it not working right. After i run this code, i have transcoded file without extention named "Orginal" in /Volumes/Victory/folder2 path. I'm doing something wrong? Original file is "/Users/victor/Desktop/Folder1/B-Rolls/Original Media/Clip #21.mov" thx, Vic